# Is it possible to use Index signatures to define the shape of an interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am new to TypeScript and have been trying to find the answer to this but I'm having a hard time finding what I am looking for. I have looked at `Generic Constraints` but I do not think it is quite right.

So if I have an interface for a `Form` that looks like this:

```
interface MyFirstForm {
    myField: {
        value: string;
        valid: boolean;
        myFirstArbitraryField: string
    }
}
```

And then I wanted to define another `Form` like this:

```
interface MyOtherForm {
    myField: {
        value: string;
        valid: boolean;
        someOtherArbitraryField: number
    }
}
```

It is obvious that `value` and `valid` is common for these two so I should probably extract these in some way.

In the TypeScript docs they say that "Index signatures" can be used when you know the shape of something but not what the values would be called. So in this case could we use an interface with an `Index signature` that we extend in our arbitrary forms?

Something like this works:

```
// The common values
interface FormField {
    value: string;
    valid: boolean;
}

// The common shape that we decide all our forms must conform to.
// Record<string, any> because we want to allow for extending the field objects
interface Form {
    [key: string]: FormField & Record<string, any>;
}

// We define our Record from the Form interface so we do not loose type safety
interface ArbitraryForm extends Form {
    myField: {
        value: string;
        valid: boolean;
        arbitraryField: number
    } // & FormField would also be valid
}
```

However, normally when I extend an interface I don't have to specify the values of the interface that I am extending. In this case I will get a type error if I were to omit the `value` or `valid` fields from the `ArbitraryForm` property.

What I want to achieve is a way of extending a "shape" of an interface so that I know that whenever I create a form in my app I should extend my `Form` interface and I will have my least viable form.

Like so (though this gives type error):

```
interface FormField {
    value: string;
    valid: boolean;
}

interface Form {
    [key: string]: FormField & Record<string, any>;
}

interface ArbitraryForm extends Form {
    myField: {
        arbitraryField: number
    }
}
```

If I then had for example a function that checked for validity I could do this

```
function isFormValid(form: Form): boolean {
    return Object.values(form).every((field) => field.valid);
}
```

Thankful for any answers or pointers where I can find them!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wE834W) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Neat! That works i think! Would love for a detailed explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object types in TypeScript are already "open" or "extendible" and will allow extra properties without needing an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), and since combining nested properties with index signatures can be tricky, let's see if we can do without.

If all we want is to merge each property of your form with `FormField`, we can create a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that does this via [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types):

```
type AsForm<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] & FormField }

interface ArbitraryForm extends AsForm<{
  myField: {
    arbitraryField: number
  }
}> { }

const aform: ArbitraryForm = {
  myField: {
    arbitraryField: 1,
    valid: true,
    value: "abc"
  }
}
```

And again, since you're allowed to have extra properties, your `isFormValid()` only needs to specify that the properties are of type `FormField` and it'll just work:

```
type Form = Record<string, FormField>;
function isFormValid(form: Form): boolean {
  return Object.values(form).every((field) => field.valid);
}

isFormValid(aform); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFtXAgGwBNkBvAKGWQDc58BXCALmQGcwpQBzAbgutuCFmAI3Tp8EOCF4BfMmTABPAA4oM2ZAF5kAJQgJMhADxsOITgBo0mHHiIA+XktXIAgi3VYjAFXtbSyADaANLIoMgA1hCK6DDI3gC6zN4hCcgAZNbYuATEcmSgkLCIKK5QwsDscFCKnsgQAB6QIIQsbh42RuSUWLV2QqR8lNUVVTU5RMwgdFjC0HxyMn4kyPkGIGzIcDA2zGWjUNW1Nv7dyL0TA2fD5ZWH4-3MAIwWQ-z4gszsDK+UlDT0JjIABEcGECGBCzI+RgdBACDAwHQIDCHWwADUBIQABQ7bDMTwAShEYgkUkGlCgEDAdCgKIA8sIAFb6MAAOgBDBYuJshLZECo0EU2Nx-UJWj8MH6HKxhNk8mAaKwmI+OO2vO4yAA9FrkOgInBFPIgA)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, with the interfaces, you are not able to extend the properties of the base interface, however there is an alternative solution by using `type` instead of  `interface`

```
type FormField = {
  value: string;
  valid: boolean;
};

type MakeFormType<T extends {}> = T & FormField

type LoginForm = MakeFormType<{ name: string; surname: string }>;
```

---

## Update

Updated to cover every key, not the whole object

```
type FormField = {
  value: string;
  valid: boolean;
};

type MakeFormType<T extends {}> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] & FormField;
};

type LoginForm = MakeFormType<{
  field1: { name: string; surname: string };
  field2: { name: string; surname: string };
}>;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Would this allow for having multiple fields of the MakeFormType in the in the LoginForm?

Comment: If you mean something like nested then yes:
`
type FormField = {
  value: string;
  valid: boolean;

  nested: {
    prop: {
      a: string;
    };
  };
};

type MakeFormType<T extends {}> = T & FormField;

type LoginForm = MakeFormType<{
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  nested: {
    prop: {
      b: string;
    };
  };
}>;


// const form: LoginForm
// form.nested.prop.a // string
// form.nested.prop.b // string
`

Comment: I didnt mean nested, rather more field isntances. Like this
const LoginForm = {
    field1: { 
        value: string; 
        valid: boolean; 
    },
    field2: {
        value: string;
        valid: boolean;
    }
};

Comment: Got ya. Please check the updated solution. Let me know if there is something missing